# Finding potential function of $f(x,y)=\hat i+ 2 \,\cdot\hat j$

Tags: calculus

> Finding potential function of $f(x,y)=\hat i+ 2 \,\cdot\hat j$

**My attempt:**

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1 \, , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2$$
Integration with respect to $x:$
$$\displaystyle\int 1 dx=x+g(y)$$
Drivate with respect to $y:$
$$=1+g'(y)$$
Integration with respect to $y:$
$$=y+g(y)+c$$

The answer should be: $\boxed{f(x,y)=x+2y+c}$

> Where em I wrong?

Comment: The derivative step is wrong because the derivative of x is zero with respect to y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is find a "scalar" function $(x,y)\mapsto U(x,y)$ such that  $\nabla U=f$, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x,y)= f_1(x,y),\quad 
\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}(x,y)= f_2(x,y),
$$
where
$$
f(x,y)=f_1(x,y)\vec{i}+f_2(x,y)\vec{j}=\vec{i}+2\vec{j},
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x,y)= 1,\quad 
\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}(x,y)= 2.
$$
Therefore:
$$
U(x,y)=x+2y+C,
$$
where $C$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

When you differentiate with respect to $y$, the $x$ term should give you $0$. So you get $g'(y)=2$.